# Evaluate string without eval : Python

Tags: python, regex

Lets say I have a string `"1*5/6*(7+8)"`. I need to evaluate this string without eval. How should I go about doing it?

Comment: [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Comment: @luoluo, is that a joke?

Comment: @luoluo: 'eval' is evil.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: I attempted it but it became a bit complex. So I was asking for a better solution.

Comment: What about `ast.literal_eval` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, that will not work

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a problem for you to have `sympy` as dependency, you can use `sympy.sympify`.

```
>>> from sympy import sympify
>>> sympify("1*5/6*(7+8)").evalf()
12.5000000000000
```

Comment: Sympify also uses "eval" is not safe to use in potentially dangerous enviroments